# ActionListener not called in main class?

Tags: java, swing

So I have 2 classes, a main class and a secondary one that extends JButton and implements ActionListener. My primary class extends JFrame and implements ActionListener. When any of my custom buttons are clicked, ActionListener in the secondary is called and it performs its function (to open a file picker).

However, when I press any buttons associated with the main class (buttons that are not my custom ones), ActionListener is not called.

Here is the ActionListener code from the main class:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("ActionEvent MM");
    String ac = e.getActionCommand();
    if(ac.equalsIgnoreCase("play")){
        pl.unPause();
    }
    if(ac.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
        pl.pause();
    }
}
```

And here is the ActionListener code from the custom JButton class:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("ActionEvent MB");
    int code = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (code == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        file = fc.getSelectedFile().getName();
        if (file.substring(file.length() - 3).equalsIgnoreCase("mp3")
                || file.substring(file.length() - 3)
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("wav")) {
            super.setText(file);
            musicfile = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
        }
    }
}
```

The sysout is only for debugging purposes.

EDIT: Entire code of MusicMaker (main) class:

```
public class MusicMaker extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public static Random gen = new Random();
    public static Scanner kbr = new Scanner(System.in);

    private JButton play = new JButton(new ImageIcon("play.png"));
    private JButton stop = new JButton(new ImageIcon("stop.png"));
    private JLabel BPML = new JLabel("BPM: ");
    private SpinnerModel BPMsm = new SpinnerNumberModel(150, // initial value
            1, // minimum
            300, // max
            1); // step
    final private JSpinner BPMs = new JSpinner(BPMsm);
    private ArrayList<MusicButton> mbtn = new ArrayList<MusicButton>();
    public final CopyOnWriteArrayList<ArrayList<JCheckBox>> chbxsal = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<ArrayList<JCheckBox>>();
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private Player pl = new Player();

    public MusicMaker() {
        super("Music Maker Beta v0.1");
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            mbtn.add(new MusicButton("choose" + i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            chbxsal.add(new ArrayList<JCheckBox>());
            for (int e = 0; e < 12; e++) {
                chbxsal.get(i).add(new JCheckBox());
            }
        }
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        this.add(play, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        this.add(stop, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        this.add(BPMs, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        this.add(BPML, gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = i + 1;
            this.add(mbtn.get(i), gbc);
        }
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            for (int e = 0; e < 12; e++) {
                gbc.gridx = i + 2;
                gbc.gridy = e + 1;
                this.add(chbxsal.get(i).get(e), gbc);
            }
        }
        this.pack();
        Thread thread = new Thread(pl);
        thread.setName("Music player thread");
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MusicMaker mm = new MusicMaker();
        mm.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("ActionEvent MM");
        String ac = e.getActionCommand();
        if(ac.equalsIgnoreCase("play")){
            pl.unPause();
        }
        if(ac.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
            pl.pause();
        }
    }

    private class Player implements Runnable {
        private volatile boolean isPaused = true;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    while (isPaused) {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            lock.wait();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("test");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // handle exceptions
                }
            }

        }

        public void pause() {
            isPaused = true;
        }

        public void unPause() {
            isPaused = false;
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Entire code of MusicButton (custom button) class:

```
public class MusicButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
    public static Random gen = new Random();
    public static Scanner kbr = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Create a file chooser
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    public String file = "";
    public File musicfile;

    public MusicButton(String s) {
        super(s);
        super.addActionListener(this);
        super.setText("Choose");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("ActionEvent MB");
        int code = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (code == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = fc.getSelectedFile().getName();
            if (file.substring(file.length() - 3).equalsIgnoreCase("mp3")
                    || file.substring(file.length() - 3)
                            .equalsIgnoreCase("wav")) {
                super.setText(file);
                musicfile = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your code where you attach these ActionListeners?

Comment: I just added the entire code.

Comment: Also, when you are selecting the file you can have a Filter on which files you are only allowed to select (as i see you do some checking with mp3 files and wav files). I suggest reading up on this a little more as well.

Comment: Doesn't look like you added the listener to your buttons in your `MusicMaker` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your `ActionListener`s to your buttons to make them work. To add use this code:

```
play.addActionListener(this);
stop.addActionListener(this);
```

in your `public MusicMaker()` constructor.

In your `MusicButton` class you do this already in this line:

```
this.addActionListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized my problem! I didn't register the ActionListener with the buttons. I am tired... :P Thanks for trying anyways.